# Do we know the origin of Fontaine's idiotic laws (possible spoiler)?

Tags: genshin-impact

Soon after setting foot into Fontaine, the Traveler is greeted with a quite stupid law that Furina's tries to use to put up a show against them.

> - It is forbidden to release any flying objects during the first three days of each month

Later you learn of other "why is this even a thing" laws like:

> - It is illegal to eat ketchup on its own, as it must always be served as a condiment
> - eating cake meant for the Archon can be punishable with jail time
> - no domestic pet shall be named after Furina
> - during the dry season, all bivalves that wash ashore belong to the Hydro Archon, while other mollusks belong to the people

If we exclude the evident reference to the ["In France it is illegal to name a pig Napoleon"](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44322/was-it-ever-illegal-to-name-a-pig-napoleon-in-france) urban myth, the other laws don't seem to make any sense. Neuvilette is clearly  involved in the law making process - after all, he is the one that added the Melusine's pronouns laws - yet even he appears to consider them "intriguing".

[image]

We know that Furina never wanted to be malevolent and actually cares a lot about people, fully willing to put herself thru 500 years of pain to save them. So those don't seem things she would add as se would fully realize all the troubles she could cause.

- "eating cake meant for the Archon" is probably the only one that look like something she could have added "for fun" to keep her image  since she was pretty sure that no one would actually have the opportunity to do that in the first place
- the bivalves is plain stupid and would only have reason to exist if she really loved seafood in the first place. But she clearly prefers cake and sweets and actually shows a little dislike at the idea of eating sea creatures. And even then she wouldn't risk cause other harm just for her own gluttony.
- the flying object one would make sense if she planned to use it against the Traveler. But Lyney words seem to imply it was a thing far before the Travel went to Fontaine, so she had no way to know he would come "during the first three days of the month"
- ketchup... seems also quite odd and something she would avoid. I doubt Furina would want someone to end up arrested for such a stupid thing.

Furthermore, if we have to believe Yanfei calling Fontaine system "complicated" and many Fontaine NPC being clearly confused by their own laws it really looks like not even Fontaine citizens know all these laws in the first place.

Fontaine laws don't really make much sense even for the fake "bratty" Furina playing her role in the prophecy, and not at all for the compassionate regular girl behind the act. I also doubt Focalors is involved, even if more arrested citizens meant more trials at the Opera House and more Indemnitium.

Therefore, the question is simple: does the game point out at any other source for those weird laws or are we really meant to believe Furina added them for no real reason, even if those could seriously harm the people she was trying to save with her self-sacrifice?

(Note: the out-of-game explanation is probably quite simple: satire against over complicated law system. But I am looking for an in-game reason)

Comment: Who said that a law about the archon was added by furina herself? I guess these laws are just satire to real world weird laws, which happen to be in every nation, I guess.

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica no one said that, and that is the point. While it is true that outside-the-game the real reason is satire (I even mentioned it in the last line of the question) I am wondering if I missed some plot elements in the game since it looks quite clear that even Neuvilette himself consider half those laws pretty stupid. Basically, I am wondering if there is a lore reason that explains why they are still there and how they came to be in the first place